# Email includes styling code, modal window with contact form, email sent using php

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal, contact-form

I've created a contact form in a modal window using bootstrap. The form's action is equal to my php file that puts the message together and sends it. The email sends as it should, but in the email's message block, it includes a bit of styling code that I've not used so it has to be from the bootstrap. I'll post the code here. I've echo'd the print_r of the post and other variables and unable to fine the styling code in that output. I'm using ScotchBox for my box and it's mailcatcher to check the email status.

```
<!-- trigger modal -->
   <button id="contact-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactModal">Contact</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="contactModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h1 class="modal-title" id="contact-title">Contact Us</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="main_form">
                        <form method="post" action="send_email.php">
                            <input id="text-block" type="text" name="full_name" placeholder=" Full Name" required>
                            <input id="text-block" type="text" name="email" placeholder=" Email" required>
                            <input id="text-block" type="text" name="telephone" placeholder=" Telephone" required>
                            <br>
                            <input id="sub-button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my send_email.php file

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "someemail@email.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $subject = "Contact Request";
    $message_before =  "Full Name:  " . $full_name . "\n\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\n\n" . "Phone: " . $telephone;
    $message = strstr($message_before, "Full Name");

    mail($to, $subject, $message);

    header('Location: contact.php');
}?>
```

The email that I get in my mailcatcher has this in front of the text that should be there.

```
html.cye-enabled.cye-nm:not(*:-webkit-full-screen) body,
html.cye-enabled.cye-nm:not(*:-webkit-full-screen) #cye-workaround-body {
  -webkit-filter: contrast(48%) brightness(124%) invert(1);
}

html.cye-enabled.cye-lm body {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  border-color: rgb(2, 1, 2) !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

html.cye-enabled.cye-lm div {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  border-color: rgb(2, 1, 2) !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

html.cye-enabled.cye-lm th {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  border-color: rgb(2, 1, 2) !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

html.cye-enabled.cye-lm td {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  border-color: rgb(2, 1, 2) !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

html.cye-enabled.cye-lm input[type=text] {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  border-color: rgb(2, 1, 2) !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

html.cye-enabled.cye-lm textarea {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  border-color: rgb(2, 1, 2) !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

html.cye-enabled.cye-lm select {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  border-color: rgb(2, 1, 2) !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

html.cye-enabled.cye-lm ul {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  border-color: rgb(2, 1, 2) !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

html.cye-enabled.cye-lm .cye-lm-tag,html.cye-enabled.cye-lm.cye-lm-tag {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  border-color: rgb(2, 1, 2) !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Comment: Some email servers ignore styles

Comment: For email, it's better to put the styles in-line, rather than refer to a style block or included css file.

Comment: The email has no style added to it. But when the email actually gets sent to my mailcatcher, it has a bunch of styling in the first part of the message. It has to be from the bootstrap CSS as I've never used some of the items it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap works with jquery/javascript and should not be used for HTML emails as almost all email clients will remove javascript from the message. Use inline css or style block to add styles. There is also a framework for developing html emails:

http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html

Comment: Nothing is being used to style the emails. The contact form is created using HTML and the information gathered is passed as a variable to a php file that inputs it into the email and sends it. I've used it with no issues before until I started this project and used a modal window to present the contact form to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Site was deployed to server and is now live. The email didn't include all the style code once in a live environment. There must be an issue with Scotch-box and the virtual environment.

I've come across a few other issues that I will compile and give to the guys over at Scotch-box so they know there are some issues.